# Обращение к сайтам по ip (один ip)

Tags: apache, apache-modules, apache2.4

Есть хостинг. Выделен один ip. На нем размещены несколько сайтов.
В связи с перебоями с dns нужно наладить обращение по ip по маске: ip/alias -> папка.

Пробовал через Alias (Alias /api var/www/api), но почему-то при встрече в url слово api (example.com/api) он использует редирект на папку api. AliasMatch также не помогает.

Есть варианты как это сделать?

Comment: Вероятно api где-то переопределен. Дайте полный конфиг сервера. В Вашем случае действительно логично использовать Alias.
Еще как вариант можете использовать Rewrite...

Comment: <VirtualHost 127.0.01:80>
 ServerName api.example.com
 RewriteEngine on
 ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.01:443>
 ServerName api.example.com
 AddDefaultCharset off
 DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/api
 SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certs/api.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certs/api.key
 SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/certs/CA.CRT
 SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Пробовал ставить Alias, работает в случае 127.0.0.1/api, но и другие ссылки типо example.com/api/get тоже перенаправляет. Может я криво что-то сделал